# Variable delimiters in sorted list to string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm currently trying to convert a sorted list of characters into a string. The delimiter of this string should be '-' if the character before and after are different, but should be '&' if these characters are equal.

An example:
The list ['1', '1', '2', '9', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'] should become '1&1-2-9-A&A&A-B-C'.

This will happen for approximately 250K lists in a pandas DataFrame. I'm thinking of creating a string with all delimiters '-' and replacing them using str.replace() function, but getting stuck at the final part.

A simplificiation of my current code is as follows (where column 'sorted' contains a sorted list of the characters as above).

```
df['joined'] = df['sorted'].str.join('-')
df['correct'] = df['joined'].str.replace(r"\-(.\-)\1{1,}?", xxxx, regex=True)
```

Is there a regex pattern that can replace the xxxx that would be able to do the same part as the first pattern, with the '.' being the original character? Or is there another solution (for example a matching positive lookbehind and lookahead?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it following way:

```
import re
chars = ['1', '1', '2', '9', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C']
joined = '-'.join(chars)
result = re.sub(r'(.)-(?=\1)', r'\1&', joined)
print(result)  # 1&1-2-9-A&A&A-B-C
```

Explanation: I used positive lookahead here, checking if `-` is followed by same characters as one before. Zero-length assertion does not capture, which result in proper replacement of `-` which are 1 from each other, consider

```
A-A-A
```

Result in matches:

```
(A-)(A-)A
```

If we would use `r'(.)-\1'` as pattern it would be:

```
(A-A)-A
```

thus lefting second `-` unchanged